# How can I navigate to Home Screen if user is logged in

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I used FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges() to navigate the user to Home Screen when the user has input their email and password and click Login, but it seems that I have to click the back button before it shows the Home Screen.

Below is my code for the main.dart, where it will call AuthPage() in the home of Material App:

```
GetMaterialApp(
        enableLog: false,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Inter'),
        home: const AuthPage(),
      );
```

And here is the code for the AuthPage():

```
import 'package:catan/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:catan/screens/onboarding_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AuthPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          // user logged in
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return const HomeScreen();

            // user is NOT logged in
          } else {
            return const OnboardingScreen();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Finally the LoginScreen() which has a button that calls:

```
  void loginUser() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text);
  }
```

Note: The LoginScreen() can be accessed through a button in OnboardingScreen() with navigation.

Comment: U r missing one thing, look u r trying to check AuthStateChanges inside of a scaffold, if it has data then go to HomePage() in this case ur State looks like this Scaffold( body: HomePage())..  Soo my suggestion is  just remove the Scaffold from ur AuthPage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if `AuthPage` is rebuilt on `authStateChanges` and shows `HomeScreen`, since you pushed `LoginScreen` to the navigation stack, `LoginScreen` will remain there. That's why you have to navigate back.

To solve this, remove `LoginScreen` from the navigation after the user has signed in. Also make sure to use `try-catch` to catch errors, like wrong password etc.

```
void loginUser() async {
try {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text);
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  // handle Firebase Auth exceptions here
} catch (e) {
  // handle other errors like network issues
}
```